# How to set up identity emails for SendGrid for ASP.NET 4.6.1

Tags: sendgrid, asp.net-4.6

SendGrid advises using its Version 6.3, but that only supports .NET 4.5 ; My app is 4.6.1 and is serving on an Azure app service.

I want to try to send smtp through SendGrid and see only [this page](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/csharp.html#-Using-NETs-Builtin-SMTP-Library) for documentation. It does not show how to write the message in the IdentityConfig class and it does not say how/where to reference the SendGrid apikey via Azure's Environment Variable storage https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/csharp.html#-Using-NETs-Builtin-SMTP-Library.

I'd really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: SendGrid's latest version appears to be [9.9, in nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SendGrid). Where are you seeing 6.3?

Comment: I got errors using 9.9 that I googled and was advised to go to 6,3, which I got from Nuget by specifying the version with the install command.

Comment: Apologies if the title of this question is confusing. I was having trouble getting the v3 code to run and saw a readme that said the latest stable version was 6.3 . I could not make 6.3 work, so went back to the most recent version, as shown in the answer below. I must caution that, at least in my case, the code fails silently on localhost but works in production.

Answer (score 2):

I looked again at the SendGrid documentation and saw that the updates in late 2017 didn't say that the api only targeted 4.5.*, so decided to try the most recent version, 9.8 .

It worked with the Register Post method out of the box, simply adding a redirect to a "confirmationsent" view.

Here's the code that works for me:

```
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {

        return configSendGridasync(message);
    }

    private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
   var apiKey = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_APIKEY");
       var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

       var msg = new SendGridMessage();

      msg.AddTo(message.Destination);
      msg.From = new EmailAddress("info@XXX.org", "Website Name");
     msg.Subject = message.Subject;
      msg.PlainTextContent = message.Body;
     msg.HtmlContent = message.Body;
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```